# NestJS / TypeORM join two tables from two different database

Tags: join, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to make a query in **nestjs** using **typeorm** to **join two table from two different databases.**
Searching online, I can't find any guide about it and probably I noticed that typeorm can't do that, is there a way to do it with or without typeorm?

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: short answer no, but you can join the tables using two connections as explained in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to run the query into the two databases with two connections, get the data and make the merge/join of the results via typescript.

TypeORM is not made to join two tables between two databases.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to write a raw query.

It doesn't have the advantages of being able to provide the entity structure around it, so you'll have to validate and add entities via `.create()`.

```
const yourValidationAndTypeEnforcement = (input: any) => {
  if (!('field1' in input && typeof input.field1 === 'string')) {
    throw new Error('Expected field1 of type string');
  }
  // handle any other validation. 
  // the below is really simplified. you'll probably have to do a little bit more on the entity side and break down which fields belong to which pa
  return manager.create(YourEntity, input);
}
// Raw query does the join the way you would in any SQL client.
const result = await manager.query(`SELECT * FROM db1.sourcetable as ST1 LEFT JOIN db2.sourcetable as ST2 ON ST1.some_id = ST2.some_matching_id`);
// Then take the raw result and loop over it to create more developer friendly entities or POJOs.
const tidiedAndTyped = result.map(yourValidationAndTypeEnforcement);
```

I realise that isn't much to go on, but hopefully demonstrates a way to get past an issue like this.